# When dealing with high dimensional data we can not use a subset of the dimensions, when performing cluster analysis

Tags: clustering

Is this statement true or false?

When dealing with high dimensional data we can not use  a subset of the dimensions, when performing cluster analysis

Comment: Why should we be unable to do so? We can even use 0 dimensions, the result will just be useless...

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you transform the data.  For instance, with PCA, you may discover that there are only a few "latent" dimensions that are significant, because there may be constraints on the possible values.  But those dimensions typically don't match up with the original feature space - you in effect only discard dimensions after transforming coordinates.  For instance, consider measurements of 3 flows in pipes around a pipe junction, say, two flows x1 and x2 in and one flow  out x3). In reality, there is a material balance constraint that x1 + x2 = x3. All possible values of x1, x2, and x3 have to lie that surface, other than variations for noise.  There's just 2 dimensions of real behavior in the 3-dimensional space, but you shouldn't ignore either any of the original dimensions in coordinates x1, x2, x3.  With PCA, you can find out how to rotate the coordinates to focus on the significant behavior.

You might have other reasons or tests for discarding dimensions even in the original feature space.  The point is that it may take some testing using some other method (like PCA) than just basic clustering.